# How to print on the same line an multiline output from a loop while keeping the format?

Tags: python, output

I'm trying to solve the Arithmethic Formater from FCC. This block of code prints a arithmethic operation. The block is inside a loop which looks over if an argument is an operation. one of the task is print the output in the same line with 4 spaces that separate the expresions. What can I do to print the output in the same line while keeping the format? I tried print(,end='') but I't doesn't keep the format

```
     if(print_result is None):
        print(
            first_number.rjust(dash_to_print + 1, ' '), '\n',
            operator , second_number.rjust(dash_to_print - 2, ' '), '\n',
            '_'*dash_to_print)
```

Comment: Give examples of some values for *first_number* and *second_number* and the required output

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to use more something like formated strings (f-string) in python

```
print(f"variableNameIs: {variable:amountDigitsAsNumber}")
```

```py
rankings = {"Gonzaga": 31, "Baylor": 28, "Michigan": 25, "Illinois": 24, "Houston": 21}

for team, score in rankings.items():
    print(f"{team:10} ==> {score:10d}")print(f"{team:10} ==> {score:10d}")
```

output like:

```
Gonzaga ==>   31
Baylor  ==>   25
......
```